# Soft Question : Are there still open problems in Classical Wave optics

Tags: optics

I have been revisiting my notes from my 2nd and 3rd year physics degree - especially the ones covering Fourier Optics, and other classical wave optics - and it is quite rewarding to revisit the historical / exploratory aspect of the series of discoveries, that built the foundations of this particular area.

I have been wondering :

1. Are there still unresolved problems in classical wave or geometrical optics, seen from a physical perspective (in contrast to an engineering perspective)?
2. If so, what would be the latest attempts to resolve that.

Thank you.

Edit : to release this from hold : I would define open problems as :

1. Observation confirms the existence of something, however, there is no explaination for it.
2. A value or parameter whose existence is expected, but can't be computed yet

I think this sufficiently narrows everything down...

Comment: @moderator - i think the question can be directly answered by referring to "recognized" boundaries of classical optics.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_physics#Atomic,_molecular_and_optical_physics) is exhaustive, the Abraham-Minkowski controversy is the only mainstream accepted problem I can come up with.

Comment: There are still people active in the field, notably at the Institute of Optics in Rochester.  Thus there must remain unsolved problems.

Comment: Are you sure they work on geometric and classical optics?

Comment: Absolutely.  Miguel Alonso for one.  There is in fact quite a lot of activity with Gaussian beams, Laguerre beams, etc.  There’s also quite a bit of work elsewhere on such structured beams.

Comment: Complutense Unicersity has an entire department of Optics: https://www.ucm.es/doptica/lineas-de-investigacion and also https://www.researchgate.net/institution/Complutense_University_of_Madrid/department/Departamento_de_Optica and some of it is classical.